# Time Picker does not appears in SilverStripe

Tags: php, jquery, datetimepicker, silverstripe

mysite/code/EventManage.php 
Here i am creating a time picker, but date-picker pop-up is not appearing.

```
$fields = FieldList::create(
$startDateTime = DatetimeField::create('StartDateTime', 'Start'),
HeaderField::create('TimeFrameHeader', $timeFrameHeaderText, 5),
SelectionGroup::create('TimeFrameType', array(
    "Duration//Duration" => TimeField::create('Duration', '')->setRightTitle('up to 24h')
        ->setAttribute('placeholder','Enter duration'), 
    "DateTime//Date/Time" => $endDateTime = DateTimeField::create('EndDateTime', '')
    )
),
);

$startDateTime->getTimeField()
->setConfig('timeformat', 'HH:mm') //24h format
->setAttribute('placeholder','Enter time')
->setAttribute('readonly', 'true'); //we only want input through the timepicker
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the timepickerfield module

https://github.com/sheadawson/silverstripe-timepickerfield

Then:

```
TimePickerField::create('Duration')
...
```

And for your DateTimeField:

```
$startDateTime->setTimeField(TimePickerField::create('StartDateTime'))
...
```

Comment: TimePickerField is an extension of TimeField. TimeField has a configuration setting for timeformat that can be set globally or per instance using it's setConfig method. Alternatively I believe you could also set your i18n locale to something more suitable and the TimeField would use that.

Comment: $newfield = DatetimeField::create('DateAndTime');
$newfield->setTimeField(TimePickerField::create('DateAndTime'));      and i got the Server error becouse of the second line. i want to apply the timepicker at an already made DatetimeField

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you even can show a dropdown for a `TimeField`?

For a `DateField` there is the `setConfig('showcalendar', true)` option.

I found this [silverstripe-timedropdownfield](https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-timedropdownfield) which could be the solution you are looking for.

Comment: I just want to show timepicker on my form. Can you help me for this?

Comment: I think the above plugin is your solution. I've not used it but I imagine if you include it in your project's root, run `dev/build` and then follow the README's instructions you should have a time dropdown.